# "Multy-storey span" that wraps like usual text

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I tried to shrink down my very complex problem to the following test scenario:  I have "two storey spans" with two levels on top of each other.  On the "ground level", there is a sequence of sub-spans.  In the "cellar", there are single spans (I call them labels here) that need to stay left-aligned with the first sub-span of the sequence of sub-spans on the "ground level".

Multiple of such multy-storey spans shall follow upon each other with their ground floor and cellar aligning (imagine you were coupling double-decker train cars).  Each multi-storey span should be wrappable if it's too long to fit into one line.  It should look like this (`[]` encloses sub-spans, the big multi-story spans are divided by `|`):

```
[First] [span].  |  [This] [long] [span] [should] [start] [on] [the] [same]
[A label]        |  [This is a long label]


[line] [as] [the] [short] [preceding] [one] [if] [there] [is] [enough] [space.]



[Likewise,] [the] [following] [span] [should] [start] [on] [the] [same] [line]



[as] [this] [one] [if] [space] [allows.]  |  [Another] [span]  |
                                          |  [Another label]   |


[Yet] [another] [span]                                   |  [A] [final] [span]
[A label that's longer than the "ground level" content]  |  [A final label]
```

This is the closest I got to a solution ([see result on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/AdeXuxO/1/edit)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .wrapper {
        display:inline-block;
        line-height:2em;
        padding-right:1em;
      }
      .wrapper > span:not([class]) {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        margin-bottom:2em;
        border:1px solid green;
      }
      .displayedLabel {
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        color:red;
      }
      .line {
        max-width:600px;
      }
      .labelPlaceholder {
        display:block;
        opacity:.1;
        margin-top:-2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="line">
      <span class="wrapper">
        <span>First<span class="displayedLabel">A label</span></span>
        <span>span.</span>
        <span class="labelPlaceholder">A label</span>
      </span>
      <span class="wrapper">
        <span>This<span class="displayedLabel">This is a long label</span></span>
        <span>long</span>
        <span>span</span>
        <span>should</span>
        <span>start</span>
        <span>on</span>
        <span>the</span>
        <span>same</span>
        <span>line</span>
        <span>as</span>
        <span>the</span>
        <span>short</span>
        <span>preceding</span>
        <span>one</span>
        <span>if</span>
        <span>there</span>
        <span>is</span>
        <span>enough</span>
        <span>space.</span>
        <span>Likewise,</span>
        <span>the</span>
        <span>following</span>
        <span>span</span>
        <span>should</span>
        <span>start</span>
        <span>on</span>
        <span>the</span>
        <span>same</span>
        <span>line</span>
        <span>if</span>
        <span>space</span>
        <span>allows.</span>
        <span class="labelPlaceholder">This is a long label</span>
      </span>
      <span class="wrapper">
        <span>Another<span class="displayedLabel">Another label</span></span>
        <span>span</span>
        <span class="labelPlaceholder">Another label</span>
      </span>
      <span class="wrapper">
        <span>Yet<span class="displayedLabel">A label that's longer than the "ground level" content</span></span>
        <span>another</span>
        <span>span</span>
        <span class="labelPlaceholder">A label that's longer than the "ground level" content</span>
      </span>
      <span class="wrapper">
        <span>A<span class="displayedLabel">A final label</span></span>
        <span>final</span>
        <span>span</span>
        <span class="labelPlaceholder">A final label</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The remaining problem is: There are always line-wraps before a multi-storey span that is too long to fit on one line.  In my example, the span that's too long is the second one.  In the ASCII example, the first short span (saying "First span.") is followed by the very long span on the same line.  This is not the case in the HTML example.  Rather than filling the first line before wrapping, the very long span starts on the second line, which it shouldn't.

Any suggestions how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I'm afraid the picture is much clearer in our head than in ours. We don't know what the cellar and the storeys are supposed to mean. And your labels are also spans. And the jsbin doesn't match your example. And I don't know what you want. Is the problem that the inline-blocks end up on the next line entirely, instead of partially, if there's no room?

Comment: @MrLister, thanks for spotting the JS Bin inconsistency.  I tried to make my problem a little clearer.  It's indeed challenging to transport what I'm thinking about to others' heads.  The real thing is in fact much more complex (instead of simple spans I have sequences of SVG graphics with spacing requirements of their own), but structurally, the requirements are the same as the simplified thing I try to convey here.